# WQL query for clients by minimum OS Version Number

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wql

Say I needed a WQL query to find clients running Windows 8 or greater:

WQL query Windows 8 or Greater

```
SELECT Version FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version >= '6.2'
```

Wouldn't you run the risk of this also including Versions 6.10 (assuming that in the future there will be a 6.10 before a 7.0 version of Windows)?  Isn't this just a simple string compare operation?

What is the cleanest way to write this query to get the 'expected' results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker provided me suggestion that I really liked.  Instead of trying to query for the unknown, instead filter out the incorrect versions.  There really hasn't been a lot of versions of Windows that are not compatible.  This would make the query look something like:

```
SELECT Version FROM Win32_OperatingSystem
WHERE NOT Version like "[12345].%"
  and NOT Version like "6.0.%"
  and NOT Version like "6.1.%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the version number with the decimal point and then filter by both parts in your where clause

Comment: Thanks!  How does one do that entirely within WQL, or are you suggesting that I post process the WQL query result table in some other language?

Answer (score 0):

if you can check [Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then you will find that `Version` is string data type. so its not possible to apply comparison operator on that. You can select it in a variable do string operation or convert it in float  data type.